# how to use ruby in the web?

Tags: ruby

so now (finally after 4 hours) i have installed ruby 1.9.1, rvm and passenger.

but how do i use ruby with http?

in php you just embed php with html in a .php file.

how do you do it with ruby (note: i dont want to use frameworks for that, just pure ruby + html to learn how it works).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CGI` class for that. The documentation is here with some examples [Ruby CGI doc](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html)